# Something is wrong with class_alias - PHP

Tags: php, alias

I'm trying to use class_alias on a facade \Facades\Security.

I tried this:

```
class_alias("\\Facades\\Security", "Security");
echo Security::Unique();
```

But i got an error (Class 'Security' not found in...).

The weird thing is that when i try this:

```
$facade = "Security";
class_alias("\\Facades\\" . $facade, $facade);
echo $facade::Unique();
```

It does work and i get an output from the function 'Unique'.
So somehow storing the name of the facade in a variable and accessing it from there, fixes the problem...

Can someone tell me why?

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, Unique is static.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are using `namespace` of class name.., so no need escape (`\`), try this code

```
class_alias("\Facades\Security", "Security");
echo Security::Unique();
```

### Update

You will also need to add `namespace` in alias class `B`, see sample code

```
<?php
namespace Facades;

class Security {
 public static function Unique(){
   return "Test return";
 }
}

class_alias("\Facades\Security", "\Facades\B");

echo B::Unique();
?>
```

## DEMO

Comment: i don't think there backslashes error, see demo code

Comment: @PeeHaa yes, i have already checked.. that's way i have updated my answer, probably op missed `namespace` in alias class name

Comment: I can't use backslashes without escaping because i loop through an array of facade and for each facade i create an alias:

foreach($facades as $facade) {
   class_alias("\\Facades\\" . $facade, $facade);
}

In that case, not escaping blackslashes will yield an error.

Also, i want the alias to be accessible from all namespaces.

Comment: yes there will need escape `\'` when you are using variable so are you using `namespace` in all alias?